# Xaml parsing and multithreading

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml

I'd like to load Xaml from code running in a background thread. 
I understand I would have to sync with the dispatcher. However, it fails (throws an exception).
Why?

Here is the code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                        {
                            Content = XamlReader.Parse(
                                      "<Button xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
                                               Content='Hello World'/>");
                        }));
                    }));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: "fails" ? what happens ? (probably nothing because o is created and destroyed in another thread).

Answer (score 1):

As [Pavlo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585814/xaml-parsing-and-multithreading/5585861#5585861), you need to also set your content within the Dispatcher.

However, I will say - this is fairly useless.

Remember, when you call Dispatcher.Invoke or BeginInvoke, you're explicitly saying to run that code on the UI thread.  By starting a background thread that does nothing but invoke back to the UI thread, you're effectively doing the same work on the UI thread, with the disadvantage of extra overhead being added to the system as well as harder debugging.  In this case, you should just load the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea for a couple reasons.  Are you expecting to get XAML fragments from a database or some other storage and you can't create the instances of these controls in C#? You could just create a `Button` directly.

Are you able to allow the data to drive your visualization? A good example of this is having a collection of ICommand objects (CommandViewModel, RelayCommand, etc) and a CommandView that you want to use to represent your command? In this case, it could be a `<Button>` with a binding to the CommandViewModel Title or Content property.

You're background thread could then be used to drive the population of data (collections, properties) and you're UI would be designed to flexibly accommodate the expected data patterns.